# how to map changing json property to java pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I have json like below

```
{
    "Prop1": "val1",
    "Prop2": {
        "changingpropert1": 100,
        "changingpropert2": 200
    },
}

{
    "Prop1": "val1",
    "Prop2": {
        "changingpropert3": 100,
        "changingpropert4": 200
    },
}
```

I want to map this in pojo so my pojo will be like this.

```
public class One {
    Prop2 prop2;
    }

public class Prop2 {
    private double changingpropert1;
private double changingpropert2;
    }
```

Now I want flexiblity in Prop2 class to accept both two json in above example.

Do we have any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) use this link

Comment: AFAIK we don't have any option, i have few doubts, why these field names are different how u are creating this json ? and is there possibility that these field names will go on  to 5,6,7,..etc or limited numbers only - if limited numbers why you are not declaring all in `Prop2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `Map`...

```
public class Prop2 {
    private Map<String,Double> properties;
}
```